# How to remove border of the FilterMenu in RadGrid

Tags: css, filter, telerik, border, radgrid

I use Telerik `RadGrid` to show data in the table. There is a `FilterMenu` right under the column names. This menu has black border. Is there any way to remove this border.

[image]

CSS of a `<td>` in FilterMenu:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following CSS rule to overwrite the default style defined by the RadGrid control.

```
.RadGrid_Default .rgFilterRow > td {
    border: 0!important; /** no border **/
}
```

Please note that if you apply a different skin, say Metro, then you have to change `.RadGrid_Default` to `.RadGrid_Metro`. _[RadGrid Skin] is the required suffix.

Hope it helps.